# ActionBar tabs height

Tags: android, tabs, height, android-actionbar

I want to change default ActionBar tab's height, but can't find any info about. Is there some style attribute or method to set height of tabs?
Thanks.

Comment: Refer this post [Read this post][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827762/actionbar-with-navigation-tabs-changes-height-with-screen-orientation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how you style the tabs. Although, I was having trouble actually getting the height to change. I'm not sure you can set a height via a Style to the TabView. You may have to create custom View and apply that to your tabs in your code. All the styles and attributes you need to reference are in the SDK. Look in the Values folder of the platform version you're working with. That's how I typically find out how to do this.

```
<style name="Widget.Holo.Tab" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:height">#dp</item>
</style>

<style name="Your.Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/Widget.Holo.Tab</item>
</style>
```

Comment: i think height cant be affected ....
even i did not get the solution and the things i tried did not work..
guess thats default

Answer (score 8):

You have to change the height of the actionbar in order to change the height of the tabs.

theme.xml

```
<style name="YourTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/tab_nav</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/tab_nav_text</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">80dp</item>
    ..
</style>
```

Comment: From where is the tab_nav and tab_nav_text ?

Comment: That are styles which you'll have to define on your own :) So, just placeholder.

Comment: It works but then it also changes the height of the title bar, so it looks kind'a weird.

Comment: Yes ! .... If the actionbar is splitted .... titlebar,tab,splittedbar all height change ... so this is not a feasible solution,... According to question .... only the height of tabs must be changed ... But Good to know this option

Comment: This just changes the height of the `actionBar`, and pushes the tabs up/down, but they stay the same height

Answer (score 0):

Be Aware that using

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
```

instead of

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"
```

leads to the following problem:  if you switch from [NoActionBar Activity] to [ActionBar Activity] ActionBar will JUMP