# Unable to Change ActionBar Size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I am Trying to change the Height of `ActionBar`,the code i use is shown below

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

    View view = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(),
            R.layout.actionbarview, null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(view);
}

}
```

**Values/styles.xml:**

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- general styles for the action bar -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarSize">700dp</item>
</style>
```

**Values-v11/styles.xml**

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- general styles for the action bar -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
     <item name="android:actionBarSize">700dp</item>
</style>
```

actionbarview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
android:background="#555333"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<Button
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
   <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Title mswg" />
   <Button
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
  </RelativeLayout>`
```

The problem is not the height does not change.My target sdk is 17.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: post code of actionbarview layout

Answer (score 3):

Looks similar to your code and it's strange... I have luck with this styles (values):

```
<style name="player" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="actionBarSize">90dp</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/player.ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="player.ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_bgr</item>
</style>
```

values-v11

```
<style name="player" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">90dp</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/player.ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="player.ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_bgr</item>
</style>
```

ActionBarActivity

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
....

View customView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.player_ab,null);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    //float scale = activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    actionBar.setCustomView(customView, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));//(int) (90*scale + 0.5f)));
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this-

values/dimens.xml-

```
<resources>
     <dimen name="MyActionBar">100dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Now you can use these dimensions like this-

```
<style [...]>
     <item name="android:actionBarSize">@dimen/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
```

Another Easiest Way-

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarSize">100dp</item>
        <item name="actionBarSize">100dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: @EmelElias you are writing 700dp instead of 100dp in my code?

Comment: @EmelElias values and values-v11 for portrait and landscape mode?

Comment: both values and values-11 is for portrait .i used the 100dp suggested .

Comment: i changed to 200dp still no luck

Comment: @EmelElias  i think mainly we used 2 different style xml one for portrait and one for landscape. so just create only one dimens and one style xml.

Comment: @EmelElias and once change height to 200dip.

Comment: values-v11 is the values of the API version 11,so if device has API version above 11 the resources from values-v11 will be used.

Comment: @EmelElias ok i added one another way try that. and change dp to dip in first way.

Comment: @EmelElias then try the another way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38543/discussion-between-kanwaljit-singh-and-emel-elias)

Comment: @EmelElias http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827762/actionbar-with-navigation-tabs-changes-height-with-screen-orientation this link helps you more as having same code like yours.

Comment: @EmelElias you checked link i send you?

Answer (score 2):

try this...

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
   <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/actionBarHeight</item>
   <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/actionBarHeight</item>
</style>
<style name="actionBarHeight" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
     <item name="android:height">60dp</item>
 </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

The provided solution didnt work for me until I changed

```
android:height
```

to simply

```
height
```

Because AppCompat is not part of the system.

Answer (score 0):

on `res/values/styles.xml` add this:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="height">55dp</item>
</style>
```

and on `res/values-v11/styles.xml` and `res/values-v14/styles.xml` add this:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:height">55dp</item>
</style>
```