# How to set height of actionbar tabs for android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tabs, android-styles

Basically, I want to change the height of the tabs in actionbars. This questions has been asked several times on stackoverflow, for example:

[ActionBar tabs height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286638/actionbar-tabs-height)

I have tried most of the solutions but nothing work, here is my code.

```
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">false</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">80dp</item>
    <item name="actionBarSize">80dp</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:height">80dp</item>
</style>
```

Apparently, the code only change the actionbar height, not the tab bar height as I want. Here is the picture for reference:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, the actionbar on the bottom is higher. But in actionbar mode, the tabs height remain the same.

Why is this happening? Did i miss something???
Thank you in advance :).

Solved, as mention in:

[ActionBar with navigation tabs changes height with screen orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827762/actionbar-with-navigation-tabs-changes-height-with-screen-orientation)

and

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41792

Apparently this is a bug from android sdk ... Never though I would encounter a bug like this :(. Hope this help other people.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in the documentation, it seems like it is not possible to change the tab height. But you can use a workaround - try using PagerSlidingTabStrip instead of ActionbarTabs. You can change the height in there easily.

Answer (score 0):

By setting both the Application theme attribute android:actionBarSize and the ActionBar.TabView style attribute android:minHeight (or height) to 80 dp.
A basic example:

```
<style name="ThemeHoloWithActionBar" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">80dp</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:minHeight">80dp</item>
</style>
```

Set theme in Manifest:

```
   <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeHoloWithActionBar" >
```

Activity

```
        ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
        actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionbar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        ActionBar.Tab tabA = actionbar.newTab().setText("Tab A");
        ActionBar.Tab tabB = actionbar.newTab().setText("Tab B");
        ActionBar.Tab tabC = actionbar.newTab().setText("Tab C");
        tabA.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener());
        tabB.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener());
        tabC.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener());
        actionbar.addTab(tabA);
        actionbar.addTab(tabB);
        actionbar.addTab(tabC);
```