# How can I retrieve ActionBar.Tab Height?

Tags: android, android-actionbar-tabs

I'm working with **AppCompat**  and I use the `ActionBar.Tab` to set Tab's and now I need to get `Tab` *Height* ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try -- getHeight();  -- eg--   myTab.getHeight()

Comment: @Tasos there is no getHeight() method defined for Tab

Comment: Try if this works -tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(index).getLayoutParams().height

Comment: ActionBar.Tab is deprecated. Please try using some other class like TabHost or PageTabStrip or PageTitleStrip.

Comment: what are you trying to do anyway, why do need to get the height? is your issue something like this -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827762/actionbar-with-navigation-tabs-changes-height-with-screen-orientation

Comment: @Varundroid I know that ActionBar.Tab is depricated but I don't have time to upgrade my app right now

Answer (score 0):

You can use either

```
getToolbar().getHeight();
```

or if you're using the AppCompatActivity

```
getSupportActionBar().getHeight();
```

Assuming you've set the toolbar.

Cheers

Comment: Sorry, but I'am looking for the TabBar Height not the ToolBar Height

Answer (score 0):

try with :

```
   TabHost myTabHost= getTabHost(); 
   int tabHeight = myTabHost.getTabWidget().getHeight();
```

Comment: Sorry @Elenasys, I'm using `AppCompatActivity` where `getTabHost` isn't a method member