# Height & Width of ActionBar Tab

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Can we change the height of ActionBar tab in Android ?
If I change the height of ActionBar tab the height of ActionBar  also got changed. Is this a limitation from Android, that we can't change the height of ActionBar tab independently. Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, we cannot change the height of the ActionBar or the its tabs.
And there's a good reason for that: the guys back in mountain view (Google Campus) spent [A LOT](http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html) of time researching on touch user interfaces and the action bar is a good size for a finger to be able to tap buttons on it but doesn't waste too much screen space.

Nothing stops you to simply use Window.FLAG_NO_TITLE_BAR and do everything yourself, but as bofredo said, that's complex and I can't see the reason why.

Answer (score 1):

Wondered about it too. I came to the conclusion, that the actionbar-tab-layout is forced to orientate on the ActionBar. So it is not meant to be.

Maybe there is some kind of workaround for this, but that sounds complex.

Answer (score 0):

```
<item name="android:actionBarSize">80dp</item>
```

Visit [ActionBar tabs height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286638/actionbar-tabs-height)