# How to change size of tabs on Android action bar

Tags: android, tabs

So I have a really simple app (picture below). I am using tabs and the scrolling (via swipe or by clicking the tabs) but I was wondering if I could possible change the size of the tabs somewhat dynamically.

For instance, "Home" doesn't need to be as big as "Most Recent", and there is a 4th tab that you cannot see on the screen that would ideally be seen if the tabs were smaller.

How could I go about this? I Googled around but I could not find anything relevant that seemed to work.

[image]

Comment: This might help you a little bit. 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20038573/how-to-resize-actionbar-tabs)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740199/how-to-manage-the-width-of-actionbar-navigation-tabs

Answer (score 0):

You can use title strips instead of tabs to solve this problem pretty easily:

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#PagerTitleStrip